# how to compile lapack for Matjag installation?

Tags: matlab, compilation, package

I am trying to install the Matjag package (http://psiexp.ss.uci.edu/research/programs_data/jags/) for some academic purpose. For installation, two *.A files need to be created, during compilation process and this can be done by following commands:

```
make blaslib   # to create "librefblas.a"

make lapacklib   # to create "lapacklib.a"
```

The first command is prompted easily and create the corresponding library. But the second one comes with the following error:

[image: Error 127]

Can anyone help to resolve this issue and complete the installation? Its been a long day and after many attempts, I still get the same error.

Comment: The last sentence shows the "Error 127". The other lines show the unsuccessful attempt of command to find some specific files.

Comment: I meant: do not post images where text would be sufficient.